# How can I style a solid-color image to match the text color?

Tags: css

On a website where users can submit text posts containing images and also change various formatting aspects of the website, such as the text color, I'd like to allow them to submit images that match whatever text color the viewer has chosen.

For instance, if someone wants to include a complex mathematical formula in their post, they currently have to either use very strange notation or submit an image. Readers may not be able to see this image well or at all if they have selected certain background colors.

With the system I'm hoping to implement, someone could submit an image that's a solid color with a varying alpha channel. It would be styled with CSS to be currentColor.

Blend modes don't work because they also blend with elements behind the image. I would prefer not to complicate things by drawing with JavaScript on a canvas, because I'd have to set it up to update every time the user changes their formatting. I also can't just use JavaScript to inline an SVG because that would leave the site open to XSS attacks, and users may not want to go to the trouble of constructing an SVG file where every color is set to currentColor.

Is there a way to do this? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using kahjav's pure-CSS answer, but the hue-rotate filter works in arcane ways, and I found it was far too difficult to figure out what combination of invert, brightness, and hue-rotate I would need to emulate a given CSS color. So, I came up with a method that actually uses currentColor, as I hoped I could.

I said it wouldn't work to let users specify an SVG file and then inline it with JavaScript, but I *can* use inline SVG with JavaScript. If I put an invert filter on the user's image and then use it as a mask on a rectangle with the fill set to currentColor, the results are exactly what I want. I do have to use JavaScript to generate the inline SVG, because several elements' widths and heights must be determined from the width and height of the contained image. However, I don't need to use JavaScript to update it every time the user selects a different theme.

[Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate.](https://jsfiddle.net/zL9c87md/1/) It generates inline SVG of the form:

```
<svg width="[width]" height="[height]" id="[id]" class="[class]" style="[style]">
  <defs>
    <filter id="invert" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
      <feColorMatrix values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="img" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="[image source]" width="[width]" height="[height]" filter="url(#invert)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect mask="url(#img)" width="[width]" height="[height]" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS filter and use the hue rotate function:

```
div {
    filter: hue-rotate(/*insert deg to desired color*/);
}
```

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/) is a great article on filters. You will need to change each image according to where you want it to be. The rotate is in accordance with a [color wheel](http://paletton.com/#uid=1000u0kllllaFw0g0qFqFg0w0aF).

Comment: CSS filters could work, but I'd have to re-specify the text color in HSB instead of having the luxury of using currentColor. Still, it's a lot more convenient than using a canvas!